# Justify based on child count, not child width in Tailwind CSS and align horizontally

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Run this code in the [Tailwind Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/):

```
<div class="flex justify-between">
  <div>First item</div>
  <div>Second item</div>
  <div>Third item that is very long</div>
</div>
<div class="text-center">A centered item</div>
```

This is the result:
[image]

As you can see the centered item is not aligned with the top row's middle item.

I want the center item of the top row to be placed in the center of the screen. I don't know how to do it. I tried justify-evenly but it was not effective.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not because you space your 3 items with `justify-evenly` or `justifiy-between` that those items has equal *widths*. They must have the same width so they can fit equaly on your row and therefore your *second item*'s `width` will be centered.

After it, you have to center your *second item*'s **text position** with `text-align`.

Here is the result :

```html
<div class="flex justify-between">
  <div class="basis-1/3">First item</div>
  <div class="basis-1/3 text-center">Second item</div>
  <div class="basis-1/3 text-right">Third item that is very long</div>
</div>
<div class="text-center">A centered Item</div>
```

If you want, you can remove `text-right` class on your *third item*.